# Alter data in object of arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React app, I have this type of data:

```
const data = {
  open: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'test 1'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'test 2'
  }],
  close: [{
    id: 3,
    name: 'test 3'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'test 4'
  }]
}
```

I want to iterate over each object in the `open` and `close` arrays and return the existing data with additional `type` field. E.g.:

```
const data = {
  open: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'test 1',
    type: 'alert'
  }, {...],
  close: [...]
}
```

I'm trying something like this, but it returns `undefined` instead of the altered data:

```
const expandData = (data) => {
  return Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
    return data[key].map((item, idx) => ({
      ...item,
      type: 'alert'
    }))
  })
}

// call in another method
expandData(data) // the `data` above
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x5aspec2/

Comment: The reason it's returning undefined is because the code is returning the result of the forEach call, which will always be undefined. (forEach has side effects, but doesn't return anything).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` instead of `forEach()` and return object.

```js
const data = {"open":[{"id":1,"name":"test 1"},{"id":2,"name":"test 2"}],"close":[{"id":3,"name":"test 3"},{"id":4,"name":"test 4"}]}

function expandData (data) {
  return Object.keys(data)
    .reduce((r, k) => {
      r[k] = data[k].map(o => ({...o, type: 'alert'}))
       return r;
    }, {})
}

const result = expandData(data)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```js
const data = {
  open: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'test 1'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'test 2'
  }],
  close: [{
    id: 3,
    name: 'test 3'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'test 4'
  }]
}

function expandData (data) {
  return Object.keys(data).reduce((a, b) => {
    a[b] = data[b].map(e => ({
      ...e,
      type: 'alert'
    }))
    return a;
  }, {});
}

const result = expandData(data)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: it was the spread operator causing the error. I've checked "Use BabelJS / ES2015" in the snippet for you.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to assign the new updated array from `map` to `open` and `close` properties instead of returning them.

**Your whole code is correct and you need not change any method except that.**

```
const expandData = (data) => {
  Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
    data[key] = data[key].map((item, idx) => ({
      ...item,
      type: 'alert'
    }))
  })
}

// call in another method
expandData(data);
console.log(data); //logs updated data
```

If your data is immutable than you can return a new object instead of modifying the same `data` object.

```
const expandData = (data) => {
  var result = {};
  Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
    result[key] = data[key].map((item, idx) => ({
      ...item,
      type: 'alert'
    }))
  })
 return result;
}
expandData(data);
```

Comment: that is returning the result of the forEach call, which will still be `undefined`.

Comment: Hi @SamHasler, it does not return the data but it updates the existing data. Please check it works fine

Comment: That's changing `expandData` from a function that returns a new object to one that mutates state. It's worth pointing that out because if someone wanted to have immutable data this wouldn't be suitable.

Comment: But it's not mentioned here that the data is immutable.

Comment: It doesn't say it's mutable either, so it's best to play it safe and not mutate it.

Answer (score 0):

**This approach can also be followed:**
If you need it smiple-

```
const data = {
  open: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'test 1'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'test 2'
  }],
  close: [{
    id: 3,
    name: 'test 3'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'test 4'
  }]
}

function expandData (data) {
for(let key in data){
    if(data[key] instanceof Array){
    data[key].map(obj => {
    obj.type='alert'
  })
  }
}
return data
}

const result = expandData(data)
console.log(result)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lspd8345/2/

Answer (score 0):

You could vreate new object and map the array objects with new property.

```js
const
    expandData = data => 
        Object
            .keys(data)
            .map(key =>
                Object.assign(
                    { [key]: data[key].map(o => Object.assign({}, o, { type: 'alert' })) }
                )
            ),
    data = { open: [{ id: 1, name: 'test 1' }, { id: 2, name: 'test 2' }], close: [{ id: 3, name: 'test 3' }, { id: 4, name: 'test 4' }] };

console.log(expandData(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this way, it works:

```
const data = {
  open: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'test 1'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'test 2'
  }],
  close: [{
    id: 3,
    name: 'test 3'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'test 4'
  }]
}

function expandData (data) {
  let newObj = {}

    for(let key in data) {
        const objProp = data[key];
        newObj[key] = objProp.map((item, idx) => ({
              ...item,
              type: 'alert'
            }))
    }  

  return newObj;
}

const result = expandData(data)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is returning the result of the `forEach` call, which will always be undefined. (forEach has side effects, but doesn't return anything).

use `map` instead of `forEach`:

```js
const data = { open: [{ id: 1,
                        name: 'test 1'
                      }, {
                        id: 2,
                        name: 'test 2'
                      }],
               close: [{id: 3,
                        name: 'test 3'
                      }, {
                        id: 4,
                        name: 'test 4'
                      }]
             };

const expandData = (data) => {
  return Object.keys(data).map((key) => { //<-- use map here instead of forEach
    return data[key].map((item, idx) => ({
      ...item,
      type: 'alert'
    }))
  })
}

document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(expandData(data),null,2)+'</pre>')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using lodash with `mapValues`.

```
_.mapValues(data, element=>element.map(child=>{
    child.type = alert
    return child
}))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x5aspec2/2/